# filter array of objects by property and get storeID associated to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, arraylist

I am new to stackoverflow. So pardon if i don't represent my question correctly.

I have a specific requirement for array filtering and getting property details from it when search criteria matches. Here is my requirement.

```
let userEntered = "Zone 1"

let givenArray = 
[0]: { zone: 'Zone 1', storeId: '3405'}
[1]: { zone: 'Zone 2', storeId: '3455'}
[2]: { zone: 'Zone 2', storeId: '4125'}
[3]: { zone: 'Zone 1', storeId: '5677'}
[4]: { zone: 'Zone 2', storeId: '1123'}
[5]: { zone: 'Zone 3', storeId: '9845'}
[6]: { zone: 'Zone 1', storeId: '2341'}
```

When user enters `Zone 1`, we have to search the `givenArray` and filter out those which has `zone='Zone 1'`.

Once this is done, i need to get storeId associated to it. So as per above scenario, the storeIds associated to `Zone 1` are '3405', '5677', '2341'

So my final output should be '3405', '5677', '2341'. (As a string of storeIDs separated by `,`)

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this. I am able to use regular filter method to get the arrays which has `zone=="Zone1"`. but i am unable to get `storeIds` from it and save it as a string in my output. Can someone please help/ suggest a way to do this.

Comment: filter -> map -> join. Or just use a simple `for` loop with an `if` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) operators.

```js
const userEntered = "Zone 1";

const givenArray = [
  { zone: 'Zone 1', storeId: '3405'},
  { zone: 'Zone 2', storeId: '3455'},
  { zone: 'Zone 2', storeId: '4125'},
  { zone: 'Zone 1', storeId: '5677'},
  { zone: 'Zone 2', storeId: '1123'},
  { zone: 'Zone 3', storeId: '9845'},
  { zone: 'Zone 1', storeId: '2341'},
];

const result = givenArray
  .filter(item => item.zone === userEntered)
  .map(item => item.storeId)
  .join(', ');
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{ zone: 'Zone 1', storeId: '3405'}
,{ zone: 'Zone 2', storeId: '3455'}
,{ zone: 'Zone 2', storeId: '4125'}
,{ zone: 'Zone 1', storeId: '5677'}
,{ zone: 'Zone 2', storeId: '1123'}
,{ zone: 'Zone 3', storeId: '9845'}
,{ zone: 'Zone 1', storeId: '2341'}]

var result = arr.filter(item => item.zone === "Zone 1").forEach(x=>console.log(x.storeId));
```